# Can someone improve my heap data structure code?

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

I am trying to build max heap from a random array so that i can get largest number in the root.

Also plese suggest me, how to get the size of the heap in the heapify() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int i;
void heapify(int a[],int i)    //n=node at which heapify needs to apply
{
    int size=8;
    int max=i,l=2i,r=2i+1;
    if(a[l]>a[max] && l<=size)
    max=l;
    if(a[r]>a[max] && r<=size)
    max=r;
    if(max==i) return;
    else
    a[max]^=a[i]^=a[max]^=a[i];
    heapify(a,max);
}

//Using this function to call recursively  heapify to maintain heap data structure
void build_heap(int arr[],int n)   //n : size of array
{
    for(i=floor(n/2);i>0;i--)    // n/2 because after that every node is a leaf node and they follow heap property by default
    {
        heapify(arr,i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,5,4,8,9,10,3,1};
    build_heap(arr,8); 
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a potential error in `if (a[l]>a[max] && l <= size)`. If `l` indexes off the end of the array into memory not owned by your process, this is going to crash. You need to make sure that `l <= size` is *before* trying to access `a[l]`. Same thing with your test of `a[r]` in the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine except for a few changes:

- Change `2i` and `2i+1` to be `2*i` and `2*i+1` otherwise you'll get a compilation error. Actually it should really be `l = 2*i+1` and `r = 2*i+2` because C arrays are `0-indexed`. You are assuming `1-based` indexing in your code.
- In `build_heap()`, run the loop from `[floor(n/2), 0]` (you excluded `0`'th element probably because of the reason stated in the above point).

You can pass the size of the heap as an argument to the `heapify()` function or declare it as a global variable (though it is advised to avoid global variables).